# Properly position footer

Tags: html, css

I am trying to position a footer under `#cont`, but inside the `#container`.
I tried making it so that when there is more content in `#content`, it would keep the `footer` inside the `div`, and allow me to scroll the page, but I got lost. Any idea how I should do it?

http://jsfiddle.net/a9jv7/

As you can see, more content will push it down(because it's not inside the other div, but if it's not inside, I can't set the footer to always be on the bottom of the page)

Comment: Do you want to make the footer be always visible or to make the footer look like it is always inside `#container` ?

Comment: Inside the #container, not always visible through "fixed"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the floating elements to `display: inline-block,` so you have more control over them and the container will adapt to their height.

```
#footer {
  background-color:#FFA500;
  text-align:center;
  max-width:960px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

The example: http://jsfiddle.net/frapporti/TPbCG/

---

EDIT: 
In general, I'd really like to advice you against the use of floating elements for layout, as they were pushed beyond they original intended use from the very beginning, and now we have `flex` who does magic :)

1. http://html5hub.com/after-float/
2. http://jsfiddle.net/Cerebrl/ZkQnD/

Comment: That will keep it fixed on the bottom of the page, but not "sticked" at the bottom of my #container, where I want it to be.

Comment: Yep, something like that. Just need to fix the menu not showing now.

Comment: Or check my way, that still has the menu there and is done in fewer code lines. And technically his answer is not right, his comment is.

Comment: Footer should have the same size as header, though. It's for the website not content.

Comment: ah, so you don't want it inside the container then.. code updated: http://jsfiddle.net/frapporti/TPbCG/

Comment: Your last solution alters the HTML structure, you omitted to add that in your answer.

Comment: You're right but seems to me that he's willing to adopt the right structure too (at least, didn't specify CSS only).

Comment: What you have in the answer does change the structure. Also, `float:left` is perfectly good. You get no extra "control" if you use `display:inline-block`. Just clear the float.

Comment: You do get more control, because they aren't not inline elements anymore, they are blocks. I'll also add that to do things right, now I would adopt the flex box model.

Comment: FYI, `float` has nothing to do with `inline`. The algorithm is different. When you add `float`, they still have `block` behavior. Also, the `flex` box model is not intended to replace `float` or `inline-block`. I friendly advise you to re-read the CSS theory.

Comment: I was totally wrong about that inline bit, my bad for being out too much last night, rest assured I can teach you a lot about CSS theory, don't be suppponent. And Flex is totally meant, conceived and used to achieve the desired result replacing the current techniques.

Comment: Look whos arrogant now. I didn't mean to be, I just don't want the OP to be misinformed. Flex was intended to fix the width + padding + margin problem, not to replace `float` or `inline-block`. They have different purposes. Also I can tell you 2 things that you can achieve with `inline-block` that you can't with `flex`.

Comment: You have been though, and I don't think this discussion can be of any help to anyone. Suggested reads: 1. 
http://www.sitepoint.com/give-floats-the-flick-in-css-layouts/ 2.
http://joshnh.com/2012/02/07/why-you-should-use-inline-block-when-positioning-elements/ 3.
http://designshack.net/articles/css/farewell-floats-the-future-of-css-layout/ 4. http://html5hub.com/after-float/

Answer (score 1):

If I understood what you want to achieve correctly, than this is one way to do it:

http://jsfiddle.net/a9jv7/1/

On `#container` add:

```
border-bottom:30px solid transparent; // used to add spacing bottom
margin-bottom:-30px; // used to add spacing bottom
overflow:hidden; // to give the container height, because it has none since the elements inside it are float-ed; (google clear-float).
```